# i want to store my image file from android app to server images folder using c# web service and url of image in my database

Tags: c#, android, web-services

In this android code I am sending image string value to web services to store image in server Upload folder and URL of image in database:

```
@Override
      protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

          Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

          map.put("ProImage", encodedImage);

          return map;

      }
};
```

Here I have converted my image to Base64 string format and send it to my web service using Map method

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
c.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
c.close();
Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
Log.w("path gallery......***..", picturePath + "");
img.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

thumbnail .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

     byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

     encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

On my web service, I am passing string image and then converting it into Stream bitmap and then saving it in Upload folder:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

//image
public void image(String ProImage)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }

    String resultJSON = "";

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    int i = 0;
    try
    {
        //Context.Response.Clear();
        //Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("workstation id=mylibDB.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=mihir893_SQLLogin_1;pwd=pddnvbsbzg;data source=mylibDB.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=mylibDB");
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ProImage);

        System.IO.MemoryStream streamBitmap = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);

        Bitmap bitImage = new Bitmap((Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(streamBitmap));

        System.Drawing.Image hh = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(streamBitmap);

        String strFileName = "../Upload/myfile";// my E drive folder UploadFile

        //hh.Save(Server.MapPath(strFileName));
        hh.Save(strFileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        conn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into image (image) values ('" + strFileName + "')", conn);

        // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Productname", email);

        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Images", strFileName);
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        resultJSON = ex.Message.ToString();
    }

    string status;
    if (i > 0)
    {
        status = "success";
    }

    else
    {
        status = "failed";
    }


    // resultJSON = serializer.Serialize(tableRows).ToString();
    JavaScriptSerializer js1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string strJSON = js1.Serialize(status);
    // dtmkrs.Dispose();
    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Context.Response.Flush();
    Context.Response.Write(strJSON);


}
```

The folder where I want to store my images:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.